# JHipster unit tests fail for all Rest test

Tags: jhipster

After creating a first entity, the unit test fails for all rest POST and PUT method tests with an error 415, Unsupported Media Type, And the 406 error for GET mehtod on a single entity retrieve and 500 for all In the restcontroller, I remove the produces without a luck.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myEntities", method = RequestMethod.POST), produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

I use Spring Boot 1.3.0.M2 instead 1.2.5.RELEASE in the build.

Comment: jHipster is not upgraded to work with SB 1.3.0.M2. Also take a look at this https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1600

Comment: To my reading, JHipster will be upgraded to Spring Boot 1.3 in the 3.0 release.

Comment: Also, the application works fine with those unit test failure Rest endpoints.